# Websockets sometimes send incomplete data

Tags: c++, tcp, websocket

I have a websocket server that I've built in C++ that currently serves as a basic chat server.

If I were to send a basic "hi" message the data would like this:

```
Binary: 10000001 10000010 10110110 00100110 01100101 01100011 11011110 01001111
Byte size: 8
Decoded: hi
```

But every now and then it won't send the complete message. An example of such a case is below:

```
Binary: 10000001 10000010 01110111 00100010 11011011
Byte size: 5
```

It's sending the correct data, but it's almost as if it's been cut completely in half.

My recieving code looks something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH] = ""; // (1024)

    recv(*mSocket, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);

    // Data decoding code
    // ...
}
```

My understanding of TCP is that the protocol itself would make sure that all the packets arrived at their destination. Could someone explain why I have data loss?

Comment: Are you sure the error is on the receiving side and not the sending side? Also, TCP sockets are *streaming* with not fixed packet boundaries, which means a single `recv` call can receive less than a full message, and you need to call `recv` in a loop until you have received a full message. That's why protocols built on top of TCP often have a well-specified header that often includes the length of the payload.

Comment: TCP is stream based, so you won't know for sure that every time you `recv` you get exactly one of your protocol messages. There might be two messages, or half a message - in which case if you `recv` again you'd get the second half.  It could also be that your C++ server doesn't flush after sending every message.

Comment: Ahh, right. I see, thanks. That must be it, i'm only calling it once.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the client is flushing.

Second (if I understand your question), while a WebSocket is implemented using a Socket, note that a WebSocket is not a Socket.  You cannot merely use TCP socket calls in a server to retrieve the data from a WebSocket client.  There is WebSocket framing data that is sent with every WebSocket send().  The server has inspect the incoming stream of bytes and look in the proper area in the WebSocket frame for the "message data".  Also, WebSocket data may not necessary be sent in one WebSocket frame; you also need to check the frame to see if another WebSocket frame needs to be inspected to complete the "message data".  See the IETF spec for the WebSocket protocol:  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455